# Computing Entropy properly during Molecular Dynamics simulation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, computational-physics, simulations, molecular-dynamics

When simulating simple system to test out Stat Mech (ie. non-coupled), I was able to compute entropy by [binning the particles](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) and using the [Shannon entropy formula](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html).

For more complex systems, I realized that entropy isn't calculated by binning the particles, but for [Gibb's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_entropy_formula) you need to bin the state of the system over multiple simulations. A large number of particles, this is highly dimensional due to the particles and binning will be very difficult.

How is entropy typically computed molecular dynamics and similar simulations?

Comment: There's about a dozen different methods. A basic review can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2716075/), although there are plenty of other techniques. If you give more details about your system then I may be able to point you towards a particular method.

Comment: @lemon. Thanks. So my immediate problem is trying to compute entropy to verify [On the 
classical statistical mechanics of non-Hamiltonian systems](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/epl/i1999-00139-0/fulltext/45202.html) which involve integrating the Gaussian isokinetic system ( see my [python notebook](https://github.com/aidan-plenert-macdonald/physics/blob/master/Statistical%20Mechanics/nonhamiltonian.ipynb)). Eventually, I wanted to use this in Machine Learning to constrain things like entropy and "temperature" during training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value of entropy as given by the Gibbs-Shannon expression $\sum_k -p_k\log p_k$, you are going to have to introduce some auxiliary discrete states that the system can be in (for example, system being in a phase space cell of some small dimensions), estimate their probabilities* and then evaluate the expression.

If you are interested only on thermodynamic entropy of equilibrium systems, you can avoid that and make a simulation of quasistatic heat transfer and calculate entropy as

$$
\int_i^f \frac{dQ}{T}.
$$

This gives you difference of entropy between two states, which is all that matters physically.

* probability that the system is in state $k$ given the macroscopic state variable values.